# Deleting old tomcat version and setting a new one

Tags: server, tomcat7

I had Apache Tomcat installed by `apt-get`, however I decided to get a newer one, performed `apt-get remove tomcat7` and `apt-get purge tomcat7`.

I installed a newer one means the bundled Tomcat Server in NetBeans install.

However,  Im still seeing the old fashioned page from former Tomcat install:

> ## It works !
>
> If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup
>   Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!
>
> This is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local
>   filesystem at: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html

I already set a different port in the ***`server.xml`*** file and whenever I go that site after executing the **`startup.sh`** file with sudo permissions I'm not getting any site like server (new one) isn't running.

How can I still be getting the page from old Tomcat install!?
When I execute the startup.sh log says all is set OK, so why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the tomcat7 by executing shutdown.sh in the bin folder in tomcat7 root directory.